# Can a phrase including past participle in mid be used right behind the preposition 'of '?

Tags: grammar

For all the English grammar my teacher taught me, the element put right after the preposition 'of' can be:

> 1, noun.  The leg of the desk  
>  2. gerund leading phrase which acts as a noun -
>   The result of giving your children anything they want. 
>  3. gerund leading phrase which starts with possessive pronoun- The good effect of my giving you aid in time.

However, recently I read such sentence structure following the preposition 'of', for instance,

> 1.'The spectacle of gunners using science of shatter men's body'. 
>  2.'The result of accumulated knowledge applied to practical life'.

The two examples above are not in the three conditions I know about the usage of preposition 'of'.

Can anybody analyze the grammar for me??   I make the following sentences when i try to imitate the example, and please see if they are right or not.

> 'The consequence of the troops occupying the abandoned factory' 
>   'The finding of Gus abducted and sent to an unknown place 10 years ago'

Comment: Didn't you ask this [on ELU also](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212484/can-a-phrase-including-past-participle-be-put-right-behind-the-preposition-of)? Most people have the same user name for both accounts.

Answer (score 2):

I will ignore your examples for now.

### Object of the prepositions

All prepositions(including *"of"*) are followed by an **[object](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_of_a_preposition.htm)**.

See my examples, the prepositions are in *italic* and the objects are in ***bold italic***:

- I forgot my homework *at* ***home***.
- I forgot my homework *at* ***my friend's house***.
- *With* ***his friend*** he found the movie theater.
- The interviews *by* ***radio broadcasters*** were carried live *by* ***the station***.

We call it the **[object of the preposition](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/object_of_a_preposition.htm)**. You can see that those objects are noun. Well actually, they are not. See the phrase ***his friend***, *"his"* is a possessive pronoun and *"friend"* is a noun. Together, they make a [**noun phrase**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase). Noun phrase is a combination of word(s) that acts like a noun.

### Noun phrase

You can see the components of a noun phrase [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase). And I will place some examples of noun phrase here:

- the news
- the house
- Both of my younger brothers
- the old picture of Fred that I found in the drawer

You may see that some noun phrase are long like crazy. I will explain the last one for you:

[image]

You see that the components are trying to describe *picture* which is circled around. You can also use past and present participle to describe the noun. And you can also omit *that*. You get :

- the old *printed* picture of Fred (that) I found in the drawer

Which is still a noun phrase.

### Conclusion

The fact that prepositions are followed by a noun phrase allows you to construct some sentences which do not obey the rules you have given, the prepositions are in *italic* and the objects which are a noun phrase are in ***bold italic***:

- You are standing *behind **the picture***.
- You are standing *behind **the old printed picture of Fred I found in the drawer last night***.
- You are taking a picture *of **the cat eating the mice***.
- You are taking a picture *of **the mice eaten by the cat***.

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 1 is using "of" incorrectly because "shatter men's body" is not a science, nor is it grammatically correct. If you are meaning to say "shattering men's bodies" is a science, you would have to write

> "gunners using the science of shattering men's bodies."`

Kind of like:

> "He used the science of talking to women."`

It's not really a science, but you can use creative license to say something is a science if you're claiming there's a method or formula for it, such as shattering men's bodies or talking to women.

Your sentence

> The result of accumulated knowledge applied to practical life.

is using "of" correctly but it is not a complete sentence; rather, it is a *dependent clause*, which is a clause that needs another clause to make a full sentence. You would have to add a clause to it, like:

> "His book of advice is the result of accumulated knowledge applied to practical life."
>
> "His massive fortune is the result of accumulated knowledge applied to practical life."

See, now those sentences make sense since I added another clause to them.

Your last two sentences could almost make sense if you were to add a clause to them, like:

> The consequence of the troops occupying the abandoned factory was that the
> factory burned to the ground.

Simply saying

> The consequence of the troops occupying the abandoned factory.

is not a complete sentence. It is a dependent clause.